# Set default window manager (i3) in OpenSuse

Tags: x11, opensuse, window-manager

How do I set the default window manager in OpenSuse in CLI?

I've a CLI installation and would like to set i3 as default window manager...

Comment: How do you normally login to your system? Are you using a login manager (display manager)? Which one? `gdm`?

Comment: No it's a VM and I just need a window manager... I don't use any display manager...

Comment: So how do you start X? Do you boot to the command line? And then what? You run `startx`?

Comment: I want that when I log into the system with my user, that the window manager starts without typing "startx". But "startx" also doesn't work...

Comment: Please answer my last comment. How do you do it now? Do you boot to the command line? Then what? You say `startx` does not work. What happens? Did you do what schaiba suggested? You should create a file called `.xinitrc` in your `$HOME` and add the lines from his answer there.

Answer (score 3):

Use ~/.xinitrc and startx (I understand you need no DM like KDM or GDM), and in ~/.xinitrc put `exec /usr/bin/i3` , then startx.

Comment: I'm sorry, there is no such file on the entire system (says "find / -name ".xinitrc")... Xorg-X11-Server is installed

Comment: If there isn't , create it. ;)

Comment: Using this method works but it seems that the system WM (lxdm in my case) calls the child WM (i3). You can see this easily with the tree view in htop. Would this cause any computational overhead? Is there any benefit to editing an actual system config to default to i3?